# Gaussian elimination GF(2)

Tags: systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I'm solving a system of linear equations in $GF(2)$ and have a problem with detecting free variables. For example, in the following system (the last column is a right sight of the system):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0   0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0   0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0   0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0   0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  0  0   1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1  1  0   0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0  0   1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1  1  1   0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0   0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0   0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0   0
```

variables $x_6$, $x_9$, $x_{10}$, $x_{11}$ thought to be free. But if I assign them the following values: 1, 1, 1, 1 the system doesn't have solutions, and if I assign them: 0, 0, 0, 0 the solution then exists. So, what are free variables? And how should I find them if I have an upper triangular matrix?

Comment: *But if I assign them the following values: 1, 1, 1, 1 the system doesn't have solutions*: what makes you say so?  Looks to me as though the system does have solutions

Comment: $x_{11}$ is not free. You forgot to subtract row number 6 from row number 8. In other words, your matrix is not in the row echelon form yet.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't completed the row reduction yet.

Your matrix looks like

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0   1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0   0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0   1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1   0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
```

If you subtract row six from row eight you get

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0   1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0   0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0   1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
```

To get to the row echelon form you still need to interchange rows six ans seven

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0   1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0   1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0   0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
```

From this you see that the variables $x_6$, $x_9$ and $x_{10}$ are free.

Remember: With a square matrix the number of all zero rows in row echelon form equals the number of free variables.